# Basic ajax functionality in RichFaces

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, richfaces

I have a lot of trouble finding proper, full examples on how to send values using Ajax when some event happens on the client side.

A basic example could be a list of cars. Each car has a name and an id. When a car is clicked, the id of the car is sent to the server.

What is the idiom for this in RichFaces using a4j? Or should I try this with plain jsf2?

I find easily parts of what I need but always there's some missing part that glues the thing together. Of course, there's always workarounds but I need a solid, robust way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bind the value of the component,

```
value="#{bean.selectedCar}"
```

and had to your component an a4j:support event :

E.g. for comboBox

```
<a4j:support event="onchange" action="#{bean.method}" />
```

E.g. for dataTable

```
<a4j:support event="onselectionchange" action="#{bean.method}" />
```

In the method on the bean `public void method()` you can read data of `bean.selectedCar`.

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you! Just a note for those who use RichFaces 4. a4j:support is a4j:ajax

Answer (score 1):

This may help: http://mkblog.exadel.com/2009/02/how-to-delete-a-row-in-jsf/

Comment: I'm tempted to set this as correct answer as it is more comprehensive but it is on other site, so I won't. Thanks!